# Comparison between two TRUNCATED probability density functions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Imagine a well-defined probability density function $f(x)$ is expanded and truncated to an arbitrary order N with respect to the Fourier bases. If this theoretical truncated function $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N F_n\exp(inx)$$ is approximated by another, experimentally obtained function $$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N G_n\exp(inx),$$ and I would like to quantitatively measure and compare how close my experimental results of $g$ resembles $f$ (N.B. since $f$ is truncated, it does not integrate to unity any more, so strictly is no longer a probability function), what metric is my best bet please? I saw Hellinger or Bhattacharyya distances, are they any good?

Many thanks!